# How to send "ctrl+z" with ruby Net::telnet cmd method?

Tags: ruby, telnet

here's my secnario,

I am writing a ruby client with Net::Telnet::new, the other side server is an ubuntu. 
I add an eventmachine to monitor the socket created by Net::Telnet::new.

here's my question,
for example , I send a command with cmd method:

client.cmd("ping 127.0.0.1") and then the eventmachine continue to output the response. 
I want to stop the ping process and stop the ping response , so I need to send an command "Ctrl+z"  or something to the server(like when we do with a telnet terminal).

so How can I do this with ruby? I tried 238.chr,237.chr,236.chr. those didn't work. also I tried to send 26.chr, this one stopped something. but my code hung there, I could't send another command with cmd method after I sent 26.chr.

here's some code,please ignore ws.onopen,ws.onmessage, those are just websocket in eventmachine.

```
     ws.onopen    { 
                puts "Web socket is opened"
                ws.send "terminal to the node"
                          $nodeSocket = Net::Telnet::new("Host" => "10.4.0.50","Timeout" => 10,"Prompt" => /login/ )
                          puts $nodeSocket


                $nodeSocket.cmd("String" =>"user","Match" => /Password/) { |c| ws.send c}
                $nodeSocket.cmd("String" => "password","Match" => /\$/) { |c| ws.send c}




               Thread.new do  
                   EM.run{
                          $conn = EM.watch $nodeSocket.getSocket,Foo,ws
                          $conn.notify_readable = true
                   }
                end


      }

      ws.onmessage { |msg| 
                begin 
                    puts msg

                      if msg =~ /command:(.*)/
                        puts $1
                        if $1 == "stop" 

                              $nodeSocket.cmd(26.chr) 
                              $nodeSocket.cmd("ls -l") 
                              $nodeSocket.cmd("pwd") 

                        else 

                              $nodeSocket.cmd($1) 
                        end
                      end
                      ws.send msg
                rescue
                    puts "there's an error happened"
                end



      }
```

Comment: This is just a long shot, but did you try 244.chr?